# Ruby script execution within a module

Tags: ruby

Why is is that the following fails?

```
module Test
    def test
        puts "test"
    end

    puts "testing"
    test
end
```

I get this output:

```
testing
test.rb:6:in `test': wrong number of arguments (ArgumentError)
    from test.rb:6:in `<module:Test>'
    from test.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Is it because the module hasn't been "compiled" yet, since the end keyword hasn't been reached?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a previously unused name might clear up your confusion:

```
module Test
  def my_test
    puts "my_test"
  end
  puts "testing"
  my_test
end
```

results in

```
testing
NameError: undefined local variable or method `my_test' for Test:Module
```

Inside the `module...end` block, when you invoke `my_test`, what is `self` (the implicit receiver)?  It is the module `Test`.  And there is no `my_test` "module method". The `my_test` method defined above is like an instance method, to be sent to some object that includes this module.

You need to define `my_test` as a "module method":

```
module Test
  def self.my_test
    puts "my_test"
  end
  puts "testing"
  my_test
end
```

results in

```
testing
my_test
```

If you want `my_test` as an instance method *and* you want to invoke it inside your module definition:

```
method Test
  puts "testing"
  Object.new.extend(self).my_test
end
```

gives

```
testing
my_test
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I had run into the problem with a method of a different name, and whipped up the example code to demonstrate - didn't look at the resulting error very closely, so the NameError was actually what I was interested in. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

I think the definition needs to be:

```
def Test.test
    puts "test"
end
```

Comment: That does work, but it works outside the module (w/ an 'include' line) even if I don't use the Test. prefix. Is ruby doing some name mangling on the call to test inside the module?

Comment: Putting the "Test." (or self.) in front of it defines it as a class method.  Without it, it is an instance method, which allows it to be used (mixed in) another class.

Answer (score 2):

```
module Test
  def test # This is an instance method
    puts "test"
  end

  puts "testing"
  test     # This is a call to a module method
end
```

The two are *completely* unrelated. Somewhere higher up in your inheritance chain, you have a module method named `test` which takes at least one argument. (I'm guessing it is the `Kernel#test` method, which takes two arguments.) Since you call it *without* an argument, you get an `ArgumentError` exception.

If you were to provide a little more detail about what the *actual* problem is, that you are trying to solve, it would be possible to give a better answer. Until then, here's a couple of ideas:

Make the method a module method:

```
module Test
  def self.test; puts "test" end

  puts "testing"
  test
end
```

Extend the module with itself:

```
module Test
  def test; puts "test" end

  extend self

  puts "testing"
  test
end
```

Create an instance of the module:

```
module Test
  def test; puts "test" end
end

puts "testing"
Object.new.extend(Test).test
```

Mix the module into a class, and create an instance of that:

```
module Test
  def test; puts "test" end
end

class Foo; include Test end

puts "testing"
Foo.new.test
```

Mix the module into `Module`:

```
module Test
  def test; puts "test" end
end

class Module; include Test end

module Test
  puts "testing"
  test
end
```

Mix the module into `Object`:

```
module Test
  def test; puts "test" end
end

class Object; include Test end

puts "testing"
test
```

Mix the module into the `main` object:

```
module Test
  def test; puts "test" end
end

include Test

puts "testing"
test
```

Comment: Thanks, very detailed. I wasn't looking for a solution to a problem, I was confused about the behavior I was observing. The failing code didn't belong in the module block, so I moved it out and all went well. I was just trying to understand what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

`test` is not calling the method you defined: it is invoking [`Kernel.test`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/test), which expects 2 arguments -- thus the `ArgumentError` exception.